# Get value of radio Button codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

I am trying to get the value from a radio button. I have two radio buttons 1 and 2 each having different values. When i print_r on the controller, the value is always of the second radio button even if i select the first radio button
**View**

```
<input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value= "1" name="mode" checked="checked">
<input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value="2" name="mode">
```

**Controller**

```
print_r($this->input->post());
```

How do i get the correct value of the radio button

Comment: How did you go did you try any answer yet?

Comment: Yes I did both of the answers but none seems to work

Comment: If i do $this->input->post('mode');
The value is returned is always 2 even if i select the first radio button whose value is 1

Answer (score 0):

converty your mode to 'mode[]' in array type

```
 <input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value= "1" name="mode[]">
 <input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value="2" name="mode[]">

  **in php code** 

    echo $this->input->post('mode');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean but give it ago. When you need to be able to post the radio just use `$this->input->post('mode')` then you can use it for updating table or inserting.

TRY

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

            $this->update_radio();
        }

        $sample = $this->get_radio();

        $data['radio'] = $sample['radio'];

        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
    }

    public function get_radio() {
        $this->db->where('radio_id', '1');
        $query = $this->db->get('radio');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update_radio() {
        $data = array(
            'radio' => $this->input->post('mode')
        );

        $this->db->where('radio_id', '1');
        $this->db->update('radio', $data);
    }

}
```

View

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome');?>

<?php if ($radio == 0) {?>
<input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value= "0" name="mode" checked="checked"> No
<?php } else { ?>
<input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value="0" name="mode"> No   
<?php }?>

<?php if ($radio == 1) {?>
<input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value= "1" name="mode" checked="checked"> Yes
<?php } else { ?>
<input class="payment_method_icon" type="radio" value="1" name="mode"> Yes  
<?php }?>

<br/>
<br/>
<button type="submit" >Save</button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
What i wanted was to be able to get the right value for the radio button
If i do $this->input->post('mode');
The value is always 2 even if i select the first radio button whose value is 1